# Invalid escape sequence for regex to match URL in Java

Tags: java, regex

I try to write regex to match URL in Java. I found the regex on the internet and it works fine in the online regex editor.
When i try to run it on the eclipse, it gives following error : Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )

```
(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?
```

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in Java strings you have to escape backslashes (i.e. `\` would result in the string literal `"\\"`). Thus the expression should look like this:

```
String expression = "(http|https):\\/\\/(\\w+:{0,1}\\w*@)?(\\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\\/|\\/([\\w#!:.?+=&%@!\\-\\/]))?";
```